# Is there code to display Grid onto any layout?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Trying to display grid onto layout.

Can't seem to find a way to get it to display...
Anyone know any code to display the Grid on the layout that's already been made?

Here is my current code:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    public StackLayout MainStackLayout { get; set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        MainStackLayout = new StackLayout();

        GridView Grid = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridView1);


        Grid g = new Grid { ColumnSpacing = 0, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray };
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30, GridUnitType.Absolute) });

            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 0, 0);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 1, 0);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 2, 0);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 3, 0);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 0, 1);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 1, 1);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 2, 1);
            g.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Test" }, 3, 1);
            //Display here

    }
}
```

.

```
  Layout1.axml:
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" />
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: uhhm. Are you using `Xamarin.Forms` or plain `Xamarin.Android`? how does `layout1.axml` look like? You are not displaying anithing. You are just creating views. You have to add them to a parent view.

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe Thanks for replying, I'm using Xamarin.Forms. Also, right now layout1.axml is just default. I've put the code for it in the main question. I'm quite new to android, any tips on how to add them to a parent view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things:
1. There is a special layout, GridLayout, add it in XML.
2. Configure GridLayoutManager for your views

Comment: Would it be possible to configure GridLayoutManager to look something like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Cfc.jpg

Comment: <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
</GridLayout>

Comment: Set columnCount and rowCount according to your own requirement. This chunk of code is for XML only. I am not sure if it will work in XAML or other

Comment: Thanks! it looks like its working! Is there any way to make it so the GridLayout covers the top half of the screen and a RelativeLayout covers the bottom half?

Comment: For that, in XML, use LinearLayout with orientation=vertical as parent layout which should enclose GridLayout and RelativeLayout respectively. Then, set Gravity of each of the children layout so they cover exactly cover half of the screen, like you want